# JPA Audit Null CreatedBy

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, jpa, audit

I am using spring MVC with mongodb and using auditing entities to save the creation and last edition user and time. So my AudtingEntity, from which all objects inherit from, is like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

/**
 * Base abstract class for entities which will hold definitions for created, last modified by and created,
 * last modified by date.
 */

public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity {
    @CreatedBy
    @Field("created_by")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Field("created_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private DateTime createdDate = DateTime.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Field("last_modified_by")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Field("last_modified_date")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate = DateTime.now();

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when I first save an object, but when I edit it the createdBy becomes null and the createdDate is updated also with the updating date. It happens because I'm ignoring these properties on front end and they are null when I save. A possible solution is to find the object in DB before save, then copy the properties to the updated object and save. However I don't like this solution because is needed to write this specific code for any object. I think probably there is a smarter way to solve this, configuring somehow to never update these fields in database after creation.

I tried to use the following property on these 2 fields, but didn't work: 
@Column(updatable = false)

Comment: what is the repository implementation for jpa ? spring jpa ? Can you also add the save and update method just in case?

Comment: The service method is:

public Crop create(Crop crop) {
        if (crop == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The crop object is null");
        }

        crop.setIsDeleted(false);
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(crop.getId())) {
            Crop originalCrop = cropRepository.findOne(crop.getId());
            if (originalCrop != null) {
                crop.setCreatedDate(crop.getCreatedDate());
                crop.setCreatedBy(crop.getCreatedBy());
            }
        }

        return cropRepository.save(crop);
    }*

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to format code in comment. The repository uses org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I still have to copy the values from the original object when editing it. If you find any news on it, please let me know.